# Translating an English statement to its logical equivalent

Tags: logic

Translate the sentence to its logical equivalent:

There are at least three people who are TA’s and have not taken the class

The domain is the set X. You may use the functions S(x), meaning that “x has taken the class” T(x), meaning that “x is a TA” and E(x,y), meaning that “x and y are the same person.”

I am confused between

∃x,y,z not E(x,y) & not E(x,z) & not E(y,z) & T(x) & not S(x) & T(y) & not S(y) & T(z) & not S(z)

∃x,y,z not E(x,y) & not E(x,z) & not E(y,z) & (T(x) => not S(x)) & (T(y) => not S(y)) & (T(z) => not S(z))

I've checked their truth tables, these are not logically equivalent. But intuitively, they seem to be same. "There is a TA who hasn't taken the class". Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The brackets don't even match.

Comment: There was an extra bracket. I think I've cleared it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively they are actually not the same. $T(x) ⇒ \neg S(x)$ means "( if $x$ is a TA, then $x$ has not taken the class )", which says nothing about whether $x$ is a TA or not.

Comment: So which one is the correct answer

Comment: @Aymen: Did you understand what I said about implication? If so, which one do you think is the answer and why? And why is the other wrong?

Comment: I still think that both the statements are true. Like I've said in the question, I interpret the statements this way: 1) There exists an x such that x is a T.A and hasn't taken the class. 2) There exists an x such that if x is a T.A he hasn't taken the class.
There is no difference between the two (at least in my mind). Obviously, I am missing something here

Comment: I just redrew the truth tables and I came up with this - When T(x) is false, i.e x isn't a T.A, he may or may not have taken the class and the statement is true in both cases. But, we want the statement to be true only when both T(x) and S(x) are true, i.e x is a T.A and x has taken the class. Right? So is the statement with the "and" the correct answer?

Comment: @Aymen: If you mean that you want both T(x) and ( not S(x) ) to be true, then indeed. Always remember that implication does not assert anything about whether the condition is true, so as you said if T(x) is false then ( T(x) implies not S(x) ) is true. In other words your second statement allows situations where $x$ is not a TA.